# Passing multiple delegate parameters to extension function as a list

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Consider the class hierarchy below

```
public class animal
{
}
public class lion:animal
{
}

public class cat:animal
{
}

public class Forest
{
    public List<lion> lionlist = new List<lion>();
    public List<cat> catlist = new List<cat>();    
}
```

I need all the animals from a forest.

Extension function to retrieve all the animals from a forest

```
   public static IEnumerable<TInnerObject> GetInnerBaseObjects<TInnerObject, TWrapperObject>(this TWrapperObject source,List< Func<TWrapperObject, IEnumerable<TInnerObject>>> innerObjectlist)
   {
       List<TInnerObject> retlist = new List<TInnerObject>();
       innerObjectlist.ForEach(x =>
       {
           if (x(source) != null)
           {
               retlist.AddRange(x(source));
           }
       });
       return retlist;
    }
```

All is well. But at the point of usage the extension function usage is a bit messy

```
void somefunction(Forest obj)
{      
  //.....

    var res = obj.GetInnerBaseObjects(new List<Func<Forest, IEnumerable<animal>>>()
            {
                (x)=>x.catlist , (y)=>y.lionlist     
            });
}
```

The instantiation of the  delegate list at the point of use is a bit messy. I would prefer it simpler like below code. Of course it is not valid code!

```
var res = obj.GetInnerBaseObjects(
            {
                (x)=>x.catlist , (y)=>y.lionlist     
            });
```

Any ideas to simplify this at the point of use.I don't mind rewriting the extension function

Comment: Out of curiosity...why not just use a list of animals?

Comment: @JustinPihony  because forest is an object which is deserialized from an xml file. I cant control the xml schema.One xml file contain one forest with multiple animals (from the same base).

Comment: changed the signature of somefunction(). Hopefully that will make it clear that I need to work on an object which is provided from outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would probably create a third property or method on `Forest` to do this. However, assuming you have good reasons, have you considered using `params`?

```
public static IEnumerable<TInnerObject> GetInnerBaseObjects<TInnerObject, TWrapperObject>(this TWrapperObject source, params Func<TWrapperObject, IEnumerable<TInnerObject>>[] innerObjectlist)
{
    return innerObjectlist.SelectMany(f => f(source));
}
```

Usage:

```
forest.GetInnerBaseObjects<animal, Forest>(f => f.catlist, f => f.lionlist);
```

Comment: perfect. thank you! Yes, I have a good reason for doing this.